# Slow login in GDM3

Tags: gnome, gdm

I have kinda fast laptop Dell XPS 13 with SSD

Computer loads and works really fast, but when I see GDM screen, enter user credentials I have a delay about 40 sec.

If I lock the screen when everything is loaded and will try to unlock it I will have the same 40 sec delay.

Don't see anything wrong at dmesg

Comment: Likely a PAM issue. Are you using Samba domains?

Comment: nope, haven't used it ever. Just uninstalled samba that was installed by default, locked the screen and still the same issue

Comment: since I installed 17.10, with gnome shell and wayland, I am seeing this too.

Comment: I'm also having this issue in 17.10, though I'm using X11.

Comment: Same problem. I thought it Wayland's fault, switched to X11, still same problem, at least 30 secs to be able to pass the lock screen :-( I don't have encryption on my home, nor any Samba shares.

Comment: did you have a look into `$HOME/.cache/gdm/session.log` ?

Comment: ➜  ~ ls $HOME/.cache/gdm/         
ls: cannot access '/home/tony/.cache/gdm/': No such file or directory

Comment: you have to use @Username, otherwise I don't know you answered a comment. Try to enable debugging in GDM with uncommenting `Enable=true` in `/etc/gdm3/custom.conf` - then log out/in or reboot

Comment: Enabled debugging at /etc/gdm3/daemon.conf Haven't had $HOME/.cache/gdm/session.log. But I have extracted some logs from /var/log/syslog: http://codepad.org/9IBf4DC6 This line looks weird: Feb 18 13:04:20 darkside gdm-password]: AccountsService: ActUserManager: Listing cached users, so not setting loaded property

Comment: You seem to have some `gnome-shell-extensions` installed/activated. For example @ 13:04:30 6 seconds have passed for **EasyScreenCast**, then another 6 seconds go by for this extension. Could you please try and deactivate all of them ? You can see all installed with `ls ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and deactivate them with ` gnome-shell-extension-tool -d <extension-name>` (you can activate them again with `-e`). Then reboot and see if it still hangs for 40 seconds.

Comment: I'm having the same problem here, on Ubuntu 16.04.6, since last week update. Unity and lightdm. Dell OptPlex 7050 with 240GB SSD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging by your [logfile](http://codepad.org/9IBf4DC6), some extensions seem to block your login process.

For example @ 13:04:30 6 seconds have passed for **EasyScreenCast**, then another 6 seconds go by for this extension.

### Disabling individual extensions

You can disable individual extensions via the commandline
looking up the names of the extensisons with

```
ls ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

and disabling them with

```
gnome-shell-extension-tool -d <extension-name>
```

or from `gnome-tewak-tool`

[image]

### Disabling all extensions

You can also go [Tabula Rasa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tabula_rasa#History) and delete all extensions

```
rm -rf .local/share/gnome-shell/extensions
```

---

You can find more infos on handling of extensions on the [official gnome3 wiki, here](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/Extensions#Enabling_extensions).

Comment: After deactivating everything, then reactivating each externsion one by one, I found the culprit. It was the Easyscreencast extension! Thanks Robert!